# How to connect Android Samsung 7. 0 on Linux Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: usb, android, mtp

I'm trying to connect a Google Pixel phone, with android 7.1, to a Ubuntu 16.04 laptop with a USB cable using mtp-tools. But the mtp doesn't see the phone file system and gives the error message "Get Storage information failed"

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and enter

```
$sudo mtp-detect
```

Output will show vendor and product ID. Next you need to edit the file

> /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules

If the file is missing, you need to get from

> /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules

Terminal:

```
cp /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
```

Add the following line after adding your specific vendor and product ID
`ATTR{idVendor}=="1234", ATTR{idProduct}=="5678", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="disk", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"`